# Cordova Safari Inspector

Tags: ios, cordova, google-chrome, safari, ionic-framework

I am developing hybrid ionic app for iOS and I am able to inspect my app from Safari. The problem is I can't inspect the real generated layout / code from the web inspector. This made the inspector kinda useless and most of the time I have to do the test "blindly".

How can I get the Safari web inspector to be more useful and able to inspect like when we are inspect on Chrome with crosswalk?

Comment: What does «real generated layout» mean? I'm using the inspector a lot together with cordova and it works perfect.

Comment: @Joerg I am using ionic for my app. So, a lot of pages were displayed by javascript. When I inspect from Safari, I can't see all those pages code from it. It seems like the code displayed is incomplete. How can I inspect all the code?